# OpenFST build fails

Tags: openfst

My attempts to build (on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS) OpenFST (openfst-1.8.2.post1) are failing with this error:

util.cc:23:10: fatal error: charconv: No such file or directory

My gcc and g++ versions are:

gcc --version
gcc-10 (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~18.04~1) 10.3.0

g++ --version
g++-10 (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~18.04~1) 10.3.0